# Here's my interface, so call me ...maybe

Tags: c#, casting, antlr

I'm inspecting VBA code to find obsolete code constructs - namely explicit `Call` statements, like this:

> ```
> Call DoSomething(42)
> ```

The "correct" code construct would be to omit the `Call` token and drop the parentheses - my code locates the obsolete `Call` statements and rewrites them like this:

> ```
> DoSomething 42
> ```

---

I have an `IdentifierReference` class, which I'm using to store the context of various identifier references throughout the VBA code I'm parsing. In order for my code inspection to easily locate method calls that use the obsolete `Call` syntax, I have added this method to the `IdentifierReference` class:

```
public bool HasExplicitCallStatement()
{
    try
    {
        var call = ((dynamic)Context.Parent).CALL();
        return call != null && call.Symbol.Text == Tokens.Call;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I didn't like having to handle exceptions here, so I rewrote it in a more strongly-typed way, like this:

```
public bool HasExplicitCallStatement()
{
    var memberProcedureCall = Context.Parent as VBAParser.ECS_MemberProcedureCallContext;
    var procedureCall = Context.Parent as VBAParser.ECS_ProcedureCallContext;

    return HasExplicitCallStatement(memberProcedureCall) 
        || HasExplicitCallStatement(procedureCall);
}

private bool HasExplicitCallStatement(VBAParser.ECS_MemberProcedureCallContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var statement = context.CALL();
    return statement != null && statement.Symbol.Text == Tokens.Call;
}

private bool HasExplicitCallStatement(VBAParser.ECS_ProcedureCallContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var statement = context.CALL();
    return statement != null && statement.Symbol.Text == Tokens.Call;
}
```

And now I wonder... is this *really* an improvement?

Is there any more elegant way of dealing with different types that *should* be sharing an interface but aren't? `ECS_ProcedureCallContext` and `ECS_MemberProcedureCallContext` are ANTLR-generated types, nested in the `VBAParser` class, generated from the grammar file I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to your original code.
I think a little bit of reflection will get you out of the try catch block situation.

```
public bool HasExplicitCallStatement()
{
    var theObject = ((dynamic) Context.Parent);
    if(theObject.GetType().GetMethod("CALL") != null)
    {
        var call = theObject.CALL();
        return call != null && call.Symbol.Text == Tokens.Call;
    }

    return false; 
}
```